# Hibernate does not compile the below subquery

Tags: hibernate, hql

HQL does not accept the below subquery -

SELECT ph2.password
FROM (select ph.password, ph.username from Password_History ph ORDER BY ph.password_Change_Date desc) ph2
WHERE ph2.username =  'TestUser1'  and rownum <= 5
ORDER BY rownum;

Can I write the above query in a different way so that I don't get a error .

Thanks

Comment: I don’t believe that this is a Hibernate problem. The subquery looks fine. Some database dialects don’t allow an order clause in the subquery though. Are you on MySQL? I hope by the way that storing passwords is purely an example here. You should never store passwords in a database. Look into password hashing instead. Bcrypt is a safe start.

Comment: Remove the order clause for the subquery. If the error persists, please share the stacktrace

Comment: message unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 26 [SELECT ph2.password FROM (select ph.password, ph.username from com.wyo.persistence.PasswordHistory ph ) ph2 WHERE ph2.username = ?1 and rownum <= 5 ORDER BY rownum]
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 26 [SELECT ph2.password FROM (select ph.password, ph.username from com.wyo.persistence.PasswordHistory ph ) ph2 WHERE ph2.username =  ?1  and rownum <= 5 ORDER BY rownum]

Comment: Your subquery is in the from clause. Jpql and hql dont support subqueries in the from clause. Just eliminate the subquery by using the having clause for your where clause and you should be good.

Comment: I still can't convert to HQL since I get an error on FROM  - SELECT ph2.password
FROM (select ph.password, ph.username from Password_History ph ORDER BY ph.password_Change_Date desc) ph2
WHERE ph2.username =  'TestUser1'  and rownum <= 5
ORDER BY rownum;